# Macro to find user input date range and delete everything outside range

Tags: date, excel, range, user-input, vba

Wondering if someone could help me in developing a simple user interfacing macro.

I have a set of data with the first Column (A) being dates. The date range can be an arbitrary range so could go from any start date to end date (most of the time its a 6/8 weeks). Lets say for arguments sake the date range goes from 31/12/2014 18:00 to 09/02/2015 18:00 (note date is UK format of dd/mm/yyyy). I would like the user to be asked for a start and end date range that they went - say 01/01/2015 to 31/01/2015. Once they have chosen the range the macro should delete everything BEFORE their selected date range (and shift cells up) and delete everything AFTER their selected date range. The date range is in increments of 10 minutes.

I've written some code to start off:

```
Public Sub DateRngInput()

Dim startDate As String
Dim endDate As String
Dim sRow As Long
Dim eRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
startDate = Left(Worksheets("Template").Cells(1, 1), 10)
endDate = Left(Worksheets("Template").Cells(lastRow, 1), 10)

sDate = InputBox("Choose Start date (dd/mm/yyyy)" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Data range starts at " & startDate)
eDate = InputBox("Choose End date (dd/mm/yyyy)" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Data range ends at " & endDate)

'On Error Resume Next
sRow = Worksheets("Template").Range("$A$1:$A" & lastRow).Find(sDate, LookAt:=xlPart).Row
eRow = Worksheets("Template").Range("$A$1:$A" & lastRow).Find(eDate, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookAt:=xlPart).Row

MsgBox ("Your date range is from: " & vbNewLine & sDate & " at Row " & sRow & vbNewLine & "To " & vbNewLine & eDate & " at Row " & eRow)

End Sub
```

The macro errors out at the following line with the Run-Time error '91':

```
sRow = Worksheets("Template").Range("$A$1:$A" & lastRow).Find(sDate, LookAt:=xlPart).Row
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: That error is caused because `.Find` is not finding `sdate`. I would try to force to the user to enter a valid date.

Comment: hi, did you consider using autofilter? Filtering dates may be a little bit challenging but it worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have data like:

[image]

Notice the material is not even sorted!  We wish to retain only data between 1 February 2015 and 15 February 2015.

We will loop from the bottom moving up.  We delete all rows outside the date limits

```
Sub DateKleaner()
    Dim early As Date, late As Date, N As Long
    Dim dt As Date

    early = DateSerial(2015, 2, 1)
    late = DateSerial(2015, 2, 15)
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        dt = Cells(i, 1).Value
        If dt > late Or dt < early Then
            Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

We will be left with:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Here is some code which asks the User to supply the dates:

```
Sub DateKleaner()
    Dim early As Date, late As Date, N As Long
    Dim dt As Date

    early = CDate(Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter start date:", Type:=2))
    late = CDate(Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter end date:", Type:=2))
    MsgBox early & vbCrLf & late

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        dt = Cells(i, 1).Value
        If dt > late Or dt < early Then
            Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Naturally you would probably use your own *UserForm* to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: So how would you incorporate user input into the code? Because I want the user to specify the date range by asking them to input the start and end date of their desired date range?

Comment: Thanks - this works fine. However, i was trying to avoid looping through since it is both memory and time intensive. Thus, I wanted to use the "Find" function in VBA. I posed this same question (with my code) in another forum and even provided this workbook...it ran fine for other people...so no idea why it is failing for me. Using the "Find" function cuts down the time a lot as it deals with the whole range at once rather than looping through each element. The time isn't a HUGE issue now because there is only about 5K rows...but it would be a problem when there are 50K + rows...

Comment: Fixed it! I used the CDate function on the user input - which converted the user input into Date format and thus Find function was able to find it properly! Thanks for the help!! Been staring at that code for 5

Comment: @Sudric87 ............You can use the **FIND()** method one column at a time *(if the columns are uneven)* or use **FIND()** over the entire block of cells if all the columns are the same height.